# inflation rate calculator c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build an inflation rate calculator but it doesn't work. 
I'm currently out of the country and using a school PC so all the errors appear in Korean, I've translated them but not quite understood them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double inflationRate (double startingPrice, double currentPrice);

int main()
{
    double startingPrice, currentPrice;
    char again;

    do 
    {
        cout << "enter the price of the item when you bought it: ";
        cin >> startingPrice;

        cout << "enter the price of the item today: ";
        cin >> currentPrice;

        cout << "the inflation Rate is: " << inflationRate(startingPrice, currentPrice) << "%";

        cout << "would you like to try another item (y/n)?";
        cin >> again;

    }while((again == 'Y') || (again =='y'));

    return 0;
}

double inflationRate(double startingPrice, double currentPrice)
{
    return ((currentPrice - startingPrice) / startingPrice);
}
```

1> ------ Build started: Project: testing, configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1> Build started: 2016-09-22 11:04:39 AM

1> InitializeBuildStatus:

1> "Debug \ testing.unsuccessfulbuild" are connected (touching) a.

1> ClCompile:

1> All output is up to date.

1> ManifestResourceCompile:

1> All output is up to date.

1> LINK: fatal error LNK1123: An error occurred during conversion to COFF. Or corrupted file is incorrect.

1>

1> failed to build.

1>

1> Elapsed time: 00: 00: 00.08

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, the latest 0, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: you have both a function and variable with the name `inflationRate`, change one of them

Comment: You may try to use translate.google and show us those errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a useless variable `inflationRate` instead of calling the function `inflationRate`. I think this is what you want (I'm assuming the missing `#` on the first line was a copy-paste error):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double inflationRate (double startingPrice, double currentPrice);  // <-- Missing semicolon!


int main() // <-- Not void; use int.
{
double startingPrice, currentPrice; // <-- Removed inflationRate variable.
char again;

do 
{
    cout << "enter the price of the item when you bought it: ";
    cin >> startingPrice;

    cout << "enter the price of the item today: ";
    cin >> currentPrice;

    cout << "the inflation Rate is: " << inflationRate(startingPrice, currentPrice) << "%"; // <-- Calling inflationRate

    cout << "would you like to try another item (y/n)?";
    cin >> again;

}while((again == 'Y') || (again =='y'));

return 0;

}

double inflationRate(double startingPrice, double currentPrice)
{
    return ((currentPrice - startingPrice) / startingPrice);
}
```